# Low wifi strength on Loki

Tags: wifi, networking, release-loki

Is there any wifi strength related bug on Loki or Ubuntu 16.04? I've been experiencing low strength and therefore low speed. I'm on a fresh Loki installation running on an HP Laptop with a Realtek `RTL8723BE` network adapter.

As a side note: This was one of the adapters that suffered from connection drops on Ubuntu 14.04 after sleeping them and/or after x amount of time (solved by manually updating the driver) but as non of those issues happen now I don't think it would be solved the same way.

Comment: Suffering same issue after something happened ~1 week ago. 

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new - this thing doesn't help anymore

Answer (score 2):

This is the most problematic network adapter, in order to fix it you need to perform a extensive research, some solutions works for an amount of people, and some not.

Useful links:

https://archrysler.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/ubuntu-16-04-rtl8723be/

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-configure-wifi-card-rtl8723be-on-Ubuntu-16-04